# I'm confused about booleans

Tags: javascript, meteor, boolean

I'm a very new coder and I have a question about my code in meteor.

If I have a template (called result), a function (called neww), and a number (called number and randomly generated from 0-1), how would I create a boolean inside a helper that returned a true or false value based on if number was greater than 0.5 or not? I have:

**Edit**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('number', Random.fraction());
  Session.setDefault('word', "");

  Template.hello.helpers({
    number: function () {
      return Session.get('number');
    }
  });

  Template.hello.helpers({
  word: function () {
    return Session.get('word');
  }
});

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set("number", 0+Random.fraction());
    }

  });

 Template.result.helpers({
  'neww': function(){
    return( number > 0.5 ? true : false )
  }
});

}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

But that always returns false.

Am I missing something

Comment: Where is `number` coming from?

Comment: What is `number`? Where is it set?

Comment: number is a randomly generated number from 0-1 created with Random.fraction()

Comment: if necessary i can paste my entire JS script

Comment: It's necessary because nobody can possibly have any idea what you're talking about otherwise.

Comment: Ok sorry for the confusion.

Comment: if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.setDefault('number', Random.fraction());
  Session.setDefault('word', "");

  Template.hello.helpers({
    number: function () {
      return Session.get('number');
    }
  });
  
  Template.hello.helpers({
  word: function () {
    return Session.get('word');
  }
});

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set("number", 0+Random.fraction());
    }

  });
 
 Template.result.helpers({
  'neww': function(){
    return number > 0.5
  }
});
  
}

Comment: well that looked better in the chatbox

Comment: @PatrickM edit your question. Comments are not for code samples.

Comment: It looks like js code put through one of those scramble-things when commercial companies don't want to reveal their web page secrets.

Comment: Well that's helpful.

Comment: BTW i've been coding for 2 days :P

Comment: So if you can't edit mine does anyone just flat out know how to create a random number generator that outputs you win or you lose based on the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your command from

```
return( number > 0.5 ? true : false )
```

into

```
return( Session.get('number') > 0.5 ? true : false )
```

Because you are accessing the number value across the templates

Comment: You sir, are a god among men! I give to you the utmost thanks. I've been trying to figure this out for 2 days.

Comment: @ThaiTran why not just `return Session.get('number') > 0.5;` ? Logical operators return booleans.

Comment: @DavidWeldon: it is a copy/paste :))

Answer (score -2):

In C family languages you would use the **ternary operator** ( please Google ).

It goes :
Question ? True_action : False_action ;

So for the example given above you would code:

```
    return( number > 0.5 ? true : false )
```

However, I don't know if the language you are using has this operator; please look it up.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with anything?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, I feel like i'm missing something obvious.